# Dynamic Array allocation of a type with a custom constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I have the following class and struct (stripped down for simplicity)

**a.h**

```
class A {
    B *myArray;
}
```

**a.cc**

```
A::A() {
    myArray = new B[1];
}
```

**b.h**

```
struct B {
    int number;
}
```

**b.cc**

```
B::B(int n): number(n)  {
}
```

As you can see the class `B` only has the constructor that takes an integer, so when I do `myArray = new B[1]` it throws `no matching constructor for initialization of 'B[1]'`.

How can I fix this? I've tried doing an array of pointers instead of an array of type `B` but it doesn't work because of the way information is entered into the program.

I **cannot** add a new constructor to `B`. I can only add private variables and methods. I can only use the following libraries: iostream, fstream, sstream, iomanip, string, and utility.

Comment: can you simply use `std::vector<>`?

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead.  It has functionality built in to handle non-default constructable types.  For every dynamic array, there is a vector that will solve it's problems

Comment: Check the update, I can't use the vector library

Comment: @MarkDodds All of the headers you name are in the same library as `<vector>`. That's the standard library. It wouldn't be surprising for one of the ones you named (like `string`) to be using `<vector>`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you define a constructor for `B`, you no longer have a default constructor defined for you.

When you do `myArray = new B[1];` you're trying to build an array of size 1 while calling `B`'s default constructor, but no such constructor exists!

This can be fixed by either making your own default `B` constructor, or calling the constructor you made when allocating. The latter can be done with:

```
myArray = new B[1]{5};
```

See it work here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/fjD2Kf)

Comment: "you no longer have a default constructor defined for you" - can be fixed by *writing one*, *or* if the default one is sufficient, declare it as `= default;`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Which the OP cannot do

Comment: @JesperJuhl good point. Added that creating your own default c'tor is definitely an option.

Comment: Pity you can't just take advantage of aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you don't have a default constructor to `B`. You have to provide one or at least a default value for the only parameter (also the constructor should be tagged as `explicit`.

Another option is to use a `vector`. You should avoid any explicit `delete` anyway, so it's a better option to what you have.